# Interchanging differential operator and integral sign for Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, sobolev-spaces, operator-algebras

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $D$ a first-order differential operator acting on sections of a smooth vector bundle $E$ over $M$.

Denote by $H^i(E)$ the $i^\text{th}$ Sobolev space of sections of $E$. For each $t\in [0,\infty)$, let $\psi(t)$ be an element of $H^2(E)$, so that $D(\psi(t))\in H^1(E)$. Suppose that $\psi(x,t)$ and $D\psi(x,t)$ are uniformly (in $x\in M$) bounded above by non-negative continuous function $C(t)$ and $C'(t)$ respectively, and that

$$\int_0^\infty C(t)dt\qquad\text{and}\qquad\int_0^\infty C'(t)dt$$

converge. Suppose also that the integral

$$\int_0^\infty\psi(x,t) dt$$

is an element of $H^1(E)$, so that it can be acted on by $D$.

**Question:** Is it true that

$$\int_0^\infty D\psi(x,t) dt = D\int_0^\infty \psi(x,t) dt?$$

I suspect this question might boil down to a simpler question about interchanging differentiation and integration for Sobolev spaces of functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$, although I've stated it more generally.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the equality stated at the moment really what you want? It would make more sense to me if there were a $D$ somewhere on the left hand side too.

Comment: You're right! I'll fix it. Maybe that's why no one responded...

Comment: I wonder if this helps, since $\int_0^\infty \psi(x,t)dt$ is an element of $H^1$: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/244337/alternative-definitions-of-sobolev-spaces-on-non-compact-riemannian-manifolds, then apply Theorem 2.4 of http://www.gold-saucer.org/math/diff-int/diff-int.pdf